# How make the problems window show the errors again?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make the problems window show the errors again? The Problems window showed a false error, so I pressed the right mouse button on it and ignore that message. Now, how do I get it back on?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTxAv.jpg)

I already checked that "Error Squiggles" is on. It was never off.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5ph.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmKyW.jpg)

Comment: can you provide exact steps to reproduce the problem? I don't see an item in my rich click menu to ignore C++ errors with the Cpptools extension.

Comment: The window that displays problems. I right-clicked on the issue. This opened up some options. It gave the option to ignore the error. After that, the error message disappeared. The problem is that now it doesn't show any errors anymore, and there doesn't seem to be any way to restore the settings.

Comment: please provide a [mre] to create that ignorable problem

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't demonstrate this because the error message window is not functioning in any project. The Problems window now reads (as shown in the question's screenshot) 'no problems have been detected in the workspace,' regardless of how many errors there are in the code. In that window, when the error message appeared, right-clicking on the error message provided some options, one of which was to 'hide the error message' or something similar. Well, now it doesn't show up anymore. Nothing at all. And I can't get it back on anywhere.